# Strange Python Counter issue

Tags: python, xml

I'm trying to parse through the WURFL XML data on mobile devices to get device id and size. The parser seems to be working and I'm generating the required dictionary and array. However I'm using a counter to validate whether or not I've got a complete set of information for each device (many are incomplete) and, despite being exceedingly simple, the counter doesn't seem to work.

Here is the code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('wurfl.xml')

root = tree.getroot()

dicto = {}

for device in root.iter("device"):
    dicto[device.get("id")] = [0, 0, 0, 0]
    for child in device:
        completes = 0 #I'm defining the counter here at the 
                      #beginning of each iteration
        if child.get("id") == "product_info":
            for grand in child:
                if grand.get("name") == "model_name":
                    dicto[device.get("id")][0] = grand.get("value")
                    completes = completes+1 #If I find the first value (product 
                                            #info) count the counter up by 1.
        elif child.get("id") == "display":
            for grand in child:
                if grand.get("name") == "physical_screen_height":
                    dicto[device.get("id")][1] = grand.get("value")
                    completes = completes+1 #count up if you find the height
                elif grand.get("name") == "physical_screen_width":
                    dicto[device.get("id")][2] = grand.get("value")
                    completes = completes+1 #count up if you find the width.
        dicto[device.get("id")][3] = completes #add the count to the array 
                                               #for this key as the final value.

arrays = []

for key in dicto.keys():
    arrays.append(key)

arrays.sort()
```

And here are examples of output:

```
#array should print as [product name, height, width, counter].
#For each value (excluding the counter itself) that isn't 0,
#the value of the counter should increase by 1.
>>> dicto[arrays[16481]]
['GT-I9192', 0, 0, 1] #This counter is what is expected
>>> dicto[arrays[16480]]
[0, 0, 0, 0] #This counter is what is expected
>>> dicto[arrays[16477]]
['GT-I9190', '96', '54', 0] #This counter is not what is expected
>>> dicto[arrays[101]]
['A700', '136', '218', 0] #This counter is not what is expected
>>> dicto[arrays[0]]
['Q4350', '94', '57', 2] #This counter is not what is expected
```

Any ideas?

Edit: Just to point out, I'm going to make a quick for loop to run through the dictionary key values as their put in to ensure they are filled which will hopefully work. But I'm baffled why my original plan didn't work.

Edit2: to make what I expected clear:

I was hoping to validate the device by checking whether I had collected the full amount of data (product info, height and width). If the parser finds each piece of information it would count up by 1. As I'm looking for 3 pieces of information a full object would have a counter of 3. However I'm finding some objects with all 3 results which have a counter of 0, or 2 when they should be 3. (the counter is represented by the last item in the output array)

Edit3: added comments

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What output were you expecting?

Comment: As each value of the array is filled in I would expect the counter to increase. A value of 0 for any value (apart from the counter value in the array) would suggest no value was found. Therefore the value of the counter should match the number of items in the array that aren't 0. As a result the first example has the expected result (1 value filled so the counter == 1). The Second example follows that. But the third and fourth examples have 3 values filled with a counter of 0 (it should be 3) and the final one has 3 values but a counter of 2.

Comment: Please edit the question accordingly, highlighting what the issues are and what you would expect instead

Comment: I've added comments detailing out the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem here is that you are iterating over multiple `child`ren within each `device`, each time resetting the `completes` to `0`. Therefore you only get the count from the *last* `child`. Move `completes` outside that loop:

```
for device in root.iter("device"):
    dicto[device.get("id")] = [0, 0, 0, 0]
    completes = 0
    for child in device:
         ...
    dicto[device.get("id")][3] = completes
```

Alternatively, ditch `completes` and replace `completes = completes + 1` (which could be `completes += 1`) with `dicto[device.get("id")][3] += 1` when each item is found.

Comment: Thanks. I knew it would be something foolish.